# The dim ker of Fredholm operator is semi continuous

Tags: functional-analysis

How to show that the $$dim(Ker (F))$$ of Fredholm operator $F$ satisfies the following inequality$$dim(Ker(F+T)) \leq dim(Ker(F))$$ for $||T||$ sufficiently small?

Answer (score 2):

Let me assume the spaces are Hilbert. Then we can decompose the domain as 
$$
\ker F\oplus \ker F^\perp
$$
and the codomain as
$$
\mathrm{im}\,F^\perp\oplus F
$$
With respect to this decomposition we can write $F$ as an operator
$$
F=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\ 0& E\end{array}\right)
$$
where $E$ is invertible. Now $F+T$ is then of the form
$$
F+T=\left(\begin{array}{cc}A&B\\ C& E+D\end{array}\right)
$$
If $T$ is sufficiently small $E+D$ is also invertible. Hence if $(u,v)\in \ker (F+T)$ we must have $v=-(D+E)^{-1} C u$ where $u$ satisfies
$$
(A+B(D+E)^{-1}C)u=0.
$$
Another way of stating this is saying that $v$ is fixed once we chose an $u\in \ker (A+B(D+E)^{-1}C)$. But there at most $\dim \ker F$ such solutions to this equation. Hence the dimension of the kernel can maximally be the dimension of $\ker F$.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can remove the assumption that the spaces are Hilbert by noting that if $F$ is Fredholm there are closed subspaces $V$ and $W$ such that the domain is $\ker F \oplus V$ and the codomain is $\operatorname{im} F \oplus W$ and $F |_V$ is an isomorphism from $V$ onto $\operatorname{im} F$. Then the same idea as in the answer should work out.

Comment: @RhysSteele: I agree